# When the question off-topic and not answerable without system access etc., can we offer our service?

Tags: discussion

Understanding that a particular question is **off-topic** while the OP is novice or need help, **can we** offer our service?

Off-topic questions receive downvotes by moderators and mostly off-topic questions are left unanswered by potential helpers. Many off-topic questions are marked closed for answers, however, we can still leave comments (limited in characters). Breaking down, there are many off-topic questions which cannot be answered directly until we access the system or know the actual technical background. Those off-topic questions are still answerable by domain experts just by practical view/test/look of the system under issue/problem/context.

Since Careers from SO is shut down, we cannot recommend that to OP if we can still help them with off-topic question. Can we link to our Upwork or similar profile to get us onboard?

If offering our service is right, what is the right way to do it?
If not right, what is the good cause behind it and is that really in the SO policy? Can someone point to that?

**Why I asked this question:**

- I came across several off-topic questions (under this context) from novice users and we can reasonably help them. For example resolving critical errors on WP.
- SO Careers was a great way to apply and get hired while still contributing to SO community to have a great SO profile for employers. Missing that opportunity, I just wanted to know what is the right way to offer our professional support.
- This question wasn't asked or available on Google SERP, therefore, to let others know the right answer, I posted this.

Comment: I'm mindful that allowing this opens the door to every closed question becoming a free for all of advertisements for commercial services, especially given that advertising anything be it services or products on Stackoverflow is considered spam. I would avoid doing anything similar to this. I did take a quick look at the stack overflow meta for precedent and found none, but the general stance towards this behaviour in other situations suggests the chances of a yes are _dismal_ at best.

Comment: Upwork equals spam. That would be bad.

Comment: Okay. Good to know @TomJNowell - and why this question is downvoted, how can we know the reason. Asking a way to conduct better is downvoted? Wondering why is the meta WP is for?

Comment: I didn't downvote, you'd have to hope someone appears and explains why they did it, otherwise it's likely signalling disagreement

Comment: Downvoting a question on meta signifies disagreement with the proposal.  Whoever downvoted just doesn't like your idea of a sales pitch.

Comment: This is unethical way to disagree with the idea since this was not a proposal. It was a question expecting a clear answer with reasoning. If people start giving answer like this, I wonder there should be no comments or answer options. Downvoting clearly means this shouldn't be asked which is wrong. We can ask this question. If you see clearly again it was a clear question with discussion tag and the question content is free from proposal-stuff and feature-request tag. Just because someone is not able to understand the question context and downvoted that directly is wrong.

Comment: you can't guess why they did it or their reasons unless they come up and say so, nor is it productive to argue against it. Downvoting is a thing and the site presents it as an option, it's intended as a way to indicate the question is not useful or poorly written https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down, try not to derail your own question with this though

Comment: I agree with you on some points with exception of 'not useful or poorly written'.

Comment: I read the reference. It clearly states that: "Downvotes should be used to indicate issues with quality, effort, or accuracy of a post." - I claim this question is written with poor quality as the context is clear, readability is also good, prior effort was made too, and it was accurate under its context. - A message to downvoter: please give a reason too, be bold to give a reason of your action, and I'm really interested to know and practice rules of the community I belong to.

Comment: Also in the reference: "Downvoting is not meant as a substitute for communication and editing" - This means, the moderator cannot just downvote for 'disagreement'. Personal opinions, agreements, and disagreements have nothing to do with question's quality, effort, and accuracy.

Comment: Also in the reference: "If something is wrong, please leave a comment or edit the post to correct it." - SO promotes reasoning, guidance, correction, and a sensible gesture towards communicating our responses.

Comment: I hope this helps those with new or historical moderation privilege to understand the downvoting policy prior to making personal opinions or disagreements in the form of downvotes.

Comment: you shouldn't try to argue your way to getting the downvotes removed, I and the other moderators can neither remove them nor force the users who made them to remove them, we don't even know their identities, and we can't prevent other users from future downvoting. It won't change that it got downvoted, there is nothing you can do about that. Arguing anything in the comments on a question is counter productive however well intentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a few comments (opinion and direction), the answer to this question is **NO**, we shouldn't offer our service.

I couldn't find a straightforward SO policy fact related to this particular question, however, reading certain other policies and understanding the **reason behind them** lead to this answer.

The good cause behind this is understable by Tom J. Nowell comment on this question.

> I'm mindful that allowing this opens the door to every closed question
> becoming a free for all of advertisements for commercial services,
> especially given that advertising anything be it services or products
> on Stackoverflow is considered spam. I would avoid doing anything
> similar to this. I did take a quick look at the stack overflow meta
> for precedent and found none, but the general stance towards this
> behaviour in other situations suggests the chances of a yes are dismal
> at best.

---

About the downvotes and related comments on this question.

I welcome everyone to downvote the question and answer, but with a reason. Respect the policy by understanding its reason, context, and right way to enforce it.

Comment: On a different note, people who ask questions on WPSE, are not very likely to post jobs on Upwork anyway. And even if some people want, they can check the users and offer work using the info. from our profiles.